# Having trouble with simple event handler, c#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

first let me say that even though I am 60 years of age I am relatively new to c# and definitely new to asp.net.

I was doing a simple demo that I copied from the web, where I have a very minimal web form that only has a text box and a button. The code compiles and when run the web form it comes up and shows the proper button and text box. However, when I click the button, I should get an event to happen which does not happen. In fact, when I am debugging, I see that the program never executes to the event that increments the button click count. Of course, I am clicking the button during debug mode and I never see the click increment function executed.

Evidently the event of the button click is not being executed.

I have included a picture of the simple web form (hopefully, it will come through)

Thank You
Tom

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ViewStateDemo
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int ClicksCount = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "0";
        }
     }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClicksCount = ClicksCount + 1;
        TextBox1.Text = ClicksCount.ToString();
    }
   }
 }
```

[Simple Web Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFEnm.png)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"             Inherits="ViewStateDemo.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML so we can verify that everything is correct?

Comment: Also, pretty sure that `ClicksCount` has to be `static` for this to work

Comment: @Ignaus Although static might work for these purposes, it's generally bad in ASP.NET. Storing the click count in ViewState or Session would make more logical sense.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewStateDemo.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please give me an idea of how to post text in this comment area that can be formatted as code. I would like to post the html, as was requested, but don't know the proper way to do a reply. I really do apologize for how the above comment came out. I did attempt to format it properly but failed.

Comment: You don't post long blocks of code in the comments. You put it in your question. You include everything in your answer that helps it meet the [MCVE description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't wire up your event. You have to tell the button what method to call when it's clicked.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

By the way, you're learning ASP.NET Web Forms. Web Forms future is unclear, and bleak, and it's considered by many professionals to not be that great. If you're just starting out, you should learn [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: Mason, you were absolutely correct! Thank you for the answer and also thank you for the advice concerning asp.net. Regards Tom